# PHP geocode is working on localhost but not on server

Tags: php, google-maps, localhost, geocoding

Right, i had this all working nicely until i transfer everything over to my hosting and now this is not working

What is wrong with this code, do i need to configure something on my hosting?

here is the php, its using the google maps api

```
function getlatlang($location)  
 {  
      $geocode = file_get_contents('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address='. urlencode($location) .'&sensor=false');  

      $output= json_decode($geocode);  

      return $output->results[0]->geometry->location;  
 }  

 $objlocation = getlatlang($postcode);  
 $latitude = $objlocation->lat;  
 $longitude = $objlocation->lng;
```

I also turned on error reporting E_ALL but that showned nothing so i tryed -1 and it gave the following errors. But i never got these error while on localhost

```
Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/fa/gs/an/fagsandbooze.com/public_html/test.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/fa/gs/an/fagsandbooze.com/public_html/test.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/fa/gs/an/fagsandbooze.com/public_html/test.php on line 14

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/fa/gs/an/fagsandbooze.com/public_html/test.php on line 18

Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in /websites/123reg/LinuxPackage22/fa/gs/an/fagsandbooze.com/public_html/test.php on line 19
```

Comment: full error checking and display on ? also `var_dump($output)`

Comment: Turn error_reporting to E_ALL and see if you get any errors. do a var_dump of the response from file_get_contents to see if you are getting the expected response.

Comment: dats what i said :-)\

Comment: Have a look, i edited the post :)

Comment: the return line is 14 ? so dump the value of output, its not what you think it is

Comment: thanks that worked, it turned out i exceeded the daily requests

Comment: ok, so some basic debugging before asking next time please :-)

Comment: use a key, otherwise you will share the quota with all domains that share the particular IP

Comment: you can also buy more quote

Answer (score 0):

Always check if the php version are the same on localhost and on your hosting. Geocoder only works with php >= 7.1
https://github.com/geocoder-php/GeocoderLaravel

Answer (score -1):

it turned out that i exceeded my daily requests. opps!

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) { ["error_message"]=> string(56) "You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API." ["results"]=> array(0) { } ["status"]=> string(16) "OVER_QUERY_LIMIT" }
```

Comment: Is your server on a shared host?  Someone else might have used up the quota (you aren't using a key...).